# Calling class operator directly

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I'd like to ask you why do I need to call class operator directly in this situation:

```
void __fastcall TForm2::statusDrawPanel(TStatusBar *StatusBar, TStatusPanel *Panel,
                                        const TRect &Rect)
{
  //if (Panel == StatusBar->Panels[1]) This doesn't work for me, compiler throws E2096 Illegal structure operation
    if (Panel == StatusBar->Panels->operator [](1)) // but this is working
    {
      int i  = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm using Borland's C++ Builder XE2. I would also like to ask you in which situations do I need to call class operator directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Panels` is apparently a pointer, and when you use `[]` on a pointer, it treats it like a pointer to an array and tries to add the offset to the pointer to get a `Panels` object at the given offset, which isn't want you want.

You need to dereference the pointer, either with `Panels->operator[](1)` or `(*StatusBar->Panels)[1]` to get to the object and call `operator[]` on it, which is probably your desired behaviour.

Comment: This bites quite often with `Items` properties, where often you need to write `Foo->Items->Items[n]` where the equivalent Delphi code would be simply `Foo.Items[n]`.